# Program to find numbers whose divisors, when added together, equal the original number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've recently focused on Python and I found an exercise that I can't find the answer to. I'm supposed to find the fourth number whose divisors equal the number when added together but I just want one that can find as many as it can.

Heres my code so far but I can't figure out where its wrong:

```
new_list = []
for dividend in range(1, number+1):
    for divisor in range(1, dividend):
        if (dividend % divisor) == 0:
            if divisor in new_list:
                pass
            else:
                new_list.append(divisor)
    if sum(new_list) == dividend:
        print(dividend)
```

Comment: Such numbers belong to a special category of numbers known as `Perfect Numbers.`

Answer (score 1):

If you're calculating separately for each number, then you'll need to reset the list in between numbers - wouldn't do to calculate all the divisors of, say, 15, and then move on to 16 and already have `[1, 3, 5]` sitting there.

So, move `new_list = []` to just inside the first `for` loop.